# How to write HTML source to an HTML file with fantoccini?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I'm making a scraper and want to download the HTML source of a website so that it can be parsed. I'm using fantoccini with WebDriver to log in to the site. I have an asynchronous funct

Now that I'm logged in, what do I need to do to extract the HTML source?

What I have so far is this:

```
let htmlsrc = client.source(); 

let mut file = File::create("htmlsrc.html").unwrap();
fs::write("htmlsrc.txt", htmlsrc).await?;
```

However this gives me this error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `impl Future: AsRef<[u8]>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:44:30
   |
44 |     fs::write("htmlsrc.txt", htmlsrc).await?;
   |     ---------                ^^^^^^^ the trait `AsRef<[u8]>` is not implemented for `impl Future`
```

I'm new to Rust, so I'm not very sure of what I'm doing.

Any help would be appreciated!

The full code is this:

```
use fantoccini::{ClientBuilder, Locator, Client};
use std::time::Duration;
use tokio::time::sleep;
use std::fs::File;

use tokio::fs;


// let's set up the sequence of steps we want the browser to take
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), fantoccini::error::CmdError> {

    let s_email = "email";
    let password = "pass;

    // Connecting using "native" TLS (with feature `native-tls`; on by default)
    let mut c = ClientBuilder::native()
        .connect("http://localhost:4444").await
        .expect("failed to connect to WebDriver");

    // first, go to the Managebac login page
    c.goto("https://bavarianis.managebac.com/login").await?;

    // define email field with css selector
    let mut email_field = c.wait().for_element(Locator::Css("#session_login")).await?;
    // type in email
    email_field.send_keys(s_email).await?;   
    
    // define email field with css selector
    let mut pass_field = c.wait().for_element(Locator::Css("#session_password")).await?;
    // type in email
    pass_field.send_keys(password).await?;

    // define sign in button with xpath
    let signin_button = "/html/body/main/div/div/form/div[2]/input";
    let signin_button = c.wait().for_element(Locator::XPath(signin_button)).await?;

    // click sign in 
    signin_button.click().await?;

    let htmlsrc = c.source(); 

    let mut file = File::create("htmlsrc.html").unwrap();
    fs::write("htmlsrc.txt", htmlsrc).await?;
    
    //temp to observe
    sleep(Duration::from_millis(6000)).await;

    //c.close().await?;

    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: If you look at the error message carefully it says that you've got an `impl Future`, which probably means that you forgot to await it in this line `let htmlsrc = c.source().await;`.

Comment: @TomásVallotton yup. Thanks!